# GitIgnore, Ignorar um arquivo sem apagar ele do versionamento

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Preciso ignorar qualquer modificação em determinados arquivos, mas ao modificar qualquer coisa(nesses arquivos),ele reconhece a mudança e fica para commit,segue meu .gitignore

```
#Arquivos Diversos
*.log
*.yml
#rubocop-result.json

#coverage/
public/assets/

tmp/pids/
tmp/cache/
#!base_upload/contractual_instrument/.gitignore
base_upload/contractual_instrument/*
```

Espero ter sido especifico,caso seja necessário estou a disposição.
Obrigado desde já.

EDIT:
o arquivo .gitignore esta na raiz do projeto..

```
/home/thiago/Documentos/mt/app#
.                        Dockerfile    public
..                       files         Rakefile
app                      Gemfile       README.md
base_upload              Gemfile.lock  README.rdoc
bitbucket-pipelines.yml  .git          script
config                   **.gitignore**    sonar-project.properties
config.ru                lib           spec
db                       log           start.sh
doc                      newrelic.yml  tmp
docker-compose.yml       photos        vendor
              Rakefile      vendor
```

Alguns arquivos de inicialização *.yml não podem ser deletados,mas precisam ser modificados de acordo com o banco de dados local do dev...Por isso não pode ser deletado e nem alterado no commit..desculpem se não fui muito especifico,comecei agora a utilizar a plataforma.Obrigado

Comment: Você quer manter o arquivo no Git, mas não quer versionar as alterações? Por que?

Comment: Fiz update na pergunta

Comment: Nesse caso o mais fácil é trabalhar com dois arquivos distintos. Você mantém versionado um arquivo `foo.yml.example`, por exemplo, e não versiona o `foo.yml`. Localmente bastará o desenvolvedor copiar o `foo.yml.example` para `foo.yml` e fazer as alterações que desejar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto acontece porque você já está versionando este arquivo, e ele já está no seu repositório remoto. O que você pode fazer é:

- Salvar o conteúdo deste arquivo em um bloco de notas.
- Deletar este arquivo do seu projeto localmente.
- Comitar as modificações e dar push para o repositório remoto.
- Incluir o nome do tal arquivo no gitignore.
- Por fim, criar novamente este arquivo.

A partir de agora as modificações nele não serão rastreadas no versionamento.

Comment: Dessa forma o arquivo não sumirá do repositório remoto também?

Comment: Sim, sumirá do repositório remoto.

Comment: Então..Mas eu gostaria que ele não fosse deletado do repositório remoto,existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Então acho que não é isso que ele quer. Pelo o que entendi ele quer manter um arquivo original no repositório, mas sem versionar as alterações nesses arquivos.

Comment: @ThiagoVaz, este procedimento realmente fará com que ele suma do seu repositório remoto.